# Not able to return async await in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, asynchronous, portable-class-library, winrt-async

I have a portable class library which has a method returning `Task<string>`. When I try to use it in a Windows Store WinRT component, I get following error within WinRT component.

> Error 77  Could not resolve reference 'Assembly(Name=System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)'.

Please note that the portable class library builds fine independently. The portable class library targets following framework:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Silverlight 4 and higher
- Windows Phone 8
- .NET for Windows Store apps

Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried installing `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` into your WinRT project?

Comment: Yes, I have installed this and I can see reference to Microsoft.Threading.Tasks and Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions. But still unable to get it compiled. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the version numbers carefully. You may need an app.config [as described in Issue 2 here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same error. I tried adding App.Config in both Windows RT library and Windows store XAML based app.  Following is the entry I tried to add under app.config.                <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.16.0" newVersion="1.0.16.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

Comment: Where are you getting 1.0.16.0 from? Your version should be whatever your reference assembly is (greater than 1.5.11.0).

Comment: Sorry, its actually 1.0.12.0 and its comes from DLL Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll which comes as part of Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet (https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/1.0.16/). The version I am seeing in Reflector for that DLL is 1.0.12.0 and File Version is 1.0.16.0.

Comment: I recommending uninstalling `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` from all your projects, removing all `app.config`, and then installing the newest `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and re-installing Microsoft.Bcl.Async from all my projects but same error. I created sample hello world application to repro this. https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=aec946f9995a7b3c&page=self&resid=AEC946F9995A7B3C!115&parid=AEC946F9995A7B3C!110&authkey=!AhfZCf9N4M1vh64&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&Bsrc=Share It is uploaded at above location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft BCL team accepted this as a known issue and workaround for this issue is now documented at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx#issue7

And not to mention, it is working fine now with this workaround :)

Comment: Thanks to [Immo Landwerth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/847438/immo-landwerth) for this fix and documentation

Comment: Answers containing links only are generally discouraged as the links may become outdated and broken. Can you please include the basic details in your answer, as well as the link.